# Connecting to Oracle 11g from Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-mobile, oracle11g

I am developing smart-device project then I've been encountered these errors:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Users\king.a\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartDeviceProject4\SmartDeviceProject4\Form1.cs  46  13  SmartDeviceProject4
>
> Error 2   The type 'System.Data.Common.DbCommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    C:\Users\king.a\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartDeviceProject4\SmartDeviceProject4\Form1.cs  49  13  SmartDeviceProject4
>
> Error 3   The type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Users\king.a\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartDeviceProject4\SmartDeviceProject4\Form1.cs  52  13  SmartDeviceProject4

I've been looking for the app.config to add reference to assembly, but i couldn't find it.

Comment: whoops! why there's something wrong when i used all-caps title? oops if you don't mind i'm just asking because i do not know...

Answer (score 0):

This procedure should help you add the reference

In Visual Studio look for the **Solution Explorer** window.

- Right Click on **References**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Move to the **.Net** Tab
- Look for *Componente Name* System.Data, select and press Ok

Comment: Have you added "using System.Data" to your file?

Comment: Try to remove System.Data from reference and add it again checking the correct version is 2.0. It is possible you linked it to a newer or older version

Comment: hi i'm wandering why in smartdeviceproject don't have an app.config? any idea..???regards and thanks

Comment: mmm can't think of anything more without taking a look at the code/solution :(

Comment: not very skilled on smartdevice but it seems, looking on the net, that app.config is not supported

Comment: you're welcome! If anything should come to mind i'll write you again